# How to do a HTTP GET request using async and await

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a function that takes a url as a parameter and returns the GET Response from it, it just give me an error in the `WebResponse responseObject intialization` line

The exception is `An exception of type 'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

```
public static async Task<string> get(string url)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    WebResponse responseObject = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, request);
    var responseStream = responseObject.GetResponseStream();
    var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

    return received;
}
```

Comment: Look at Async Methods are easier to write: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: HTTPClient is not supported in windows phone 8?!

Comment: I don't think it's async that's your problem. The ProtocolViolationException points to problem being the `request.ContentType` which isn't expected for a GET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set `ContentType` for a GET request as you aren't sending any data up to the server.

> Content-Type = The MIME type of the body of the request (used with POST and PUT requests).

This is the source of your `ProtocolViolationException`.

It looks like you want to set the `Accept` header instead.

> Accept = Content-Types that are acceptable for the response

(As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields))

Try changing your code to:

```
request.Accept = "application/json";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it with HttpClient instead like this:

```
    public async Task<List<MyClass>> GetMyClassAsync(
    CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var uri = Util.getServiceUri("myservice");
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, cancelToken);
            return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<MyClass>>());
        }
    }
```

Comment: HTTPClient is not supported in windows phone 8!

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see the windows-phone-8 tag, my apologies